# How to compressing Log4net output files without using DotNetZip?

Tags: c#, log4net

I know that i can do it by using `DotNetZip` , but i want to know is there other way to compress `log4net RollingFileAppender`output wiyhot using  `DotNetZip`? 
because my application is a `Windows service` and when i use :

```
  using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {

            zip.AddFile(appenderFilePath);
            zip.Save("logs.zip");
        }
```

in `OnStart` method it give me error :

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

i thinks when i added `using (var zip = new ZipFile())` in `Onstrat` it cause to give me error, so i want to use other way, Is there other way?

Comment: I think the problem is rather with either *zip.AddFile* or *zip.Save* throwing an exception. Note that the default working directory for a service is `%WinDir%\System32`, and i guess that either *appenderFilePath* is a relative path and fails to locate the respective file in `%WinDir%\System32`, or (more likely) that your service tries to write the ZIP file into `%WinDir%\System32` which the account credentials of the service does not allow...

Comment: i write :    string appenderFilePath = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Appenders.OfType<RollingFileAppender>().FirstOrDefault().ToString(); in the service class, is it true?

Comment: Two issues there: First, are you sure that you obtain a RollingFileAppenderObject? (it could be possible that `Root.Appenders.OfType<RollingFileAppende‌​r>().FirstOrDefault()` yields `null` which then would cause a NullReferenceException for `.ToString()`). Second issue: You might obtain the *RollingFileAppende‌​r*, but .ToString() is not the right thing to do if you want to get the appender's file name - instead, you will need to access the RollingFileAppende‌​r's *File* property to get the file name. (Double-check if the file name you get is an absolute pathname)

Answer (score 1):

When using my psychic debug skills I would say your log4net zip file is locked when your are trying to zip it. Add this to your log4net configuration (appender):

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```